# Character 0 in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

The documentation for char(number) states:

> number:  A number between 1 and 255...

`=Char(1)` and `=Char(255)` works, is there any work around to get `Char(0)` or is it impossible due to zero terminated string rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that Excel uses zero-terminated strings internally.

A string returned by a VBA function which includes a null is truncated at the null when used in an Excel formula.